# How to draw a random variable from a uniform distribution using the result in html

Tags: html, random, draw, distribution, uniform

I am looking for the best way to draw an integer from a uniform distribution of numbers (range needs to be defined per case) that I then want to use to subsequently access some information.

This information is supposed to be shown in an html website.

I assume that it is not possible to write sth like this in html directly? How would I in the easiest manner embed such a function into html? I would be really thankful if you could help me. I am not looking for the actual solution but rather a hint in terms of which language to use and how to integrate into html.

Thank you!

Comment: HTML prob not can use use scripts?

Comment: You probably want to use JavaScript. What kind of data will you be accessing?

Comment: Data will be stored in a CSV of JSON kind of document. The page does not need to run online but locally on a computer for an experiment in a research lab.

Answer (score 0):

I see some sites draw the entropy from mouse move over an area, so technically you have produce a div, say 10em per 10em, attach mouse handlers and read the coordinates ( until you have large enough set ) .

You will need to normalize it later depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

How about using javascript for drawing a random number:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*101) //example to generate a random number between 0 and 100
```

and passing `var` to your html-code afterwards.